# what is the engines and the environement in whish the javascript runs?

Tags: javascript, web, development-environment, javascript-debugger

please i'm a little bit confused about how the js code runs behind the scenes and especially about the engines and the environement in whish they are working in.
so give me some examples about the js engines and explain the environement notion to me and i'm thankful in advance

Answer (score 0):

I hope following link may clear your doubts.
[Understanding How the Chrome V8 Engine Translates JavaScript into Machine Code](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-the-core-of-nodejs-the-powerful-chrome-v8-engine-79e7eb8af964)